# My university requires unrestricted access to my personal laptop. What should I do?

Tags: privacy, italy

I am not sure that Academia is the right place to post this, as it would probably be better suited for Law.se.

I am a student in Italy. My university requires unrestricted access to my personal computer for an afternoon to install a certain software. I obviously have security concerns, so I have contacted the responsible for my course to know if I could be given the key to install such software personally. He has explicitly stated that there are no alternatives to the standard process of giving in my computer to the tech department for one afternoon.

On one side am reluctant to give unrestricted access to my computer for security reasons, as I have personal files stored on my machine; on the other side I need to have access to such software because it is required for a course in the future.

Is such a request even legal or a common request in academia? How can I avoid giving unrestricted access to my personal machine while still obtaining this software?

Comment: You could buy the software on your own. If they are gifting you a license they can probably attach conditions to that, but I agree it's really icky. Especially if the software is needed for your classes. What are their options for students who do not have a personal computer? Is this software available in the computer pool? You could use that instead.

Comment: You could trick them into operating on a virtual machine that is not easily recognisable as such and encrypt everything else for good measure (keeping a backup).

Comment: Ask to be present when the tech support installs the software and stare them down sternly.

Comment: Is this a request, or a "request"? That is, what happens if you don't comply. Will it just be a minor inconvenience since you cannot use the software on your own computer, or will it have more severe consequences?

Comment: @PieterNaaijkens We have in-class assignments which require the use of such software on our personal machines; missing a certain percentage of these assignments is an automatic fail. I would call It a request.

Comment: @TheWanderer thank you for the suggestion. I have asked if this is possible.

Comment: I can't imagine an institution that is willing to use IT peoples' time to install a software on *every single student's computer*. That sounds absolutely crazy.

Comment: Is it possible to borrow a university owned laptop or use a computer at the university? As @nengel said, what about students who don't have a personal computer (or not the right operating system, if the software is OS specific)?

Comment: @Mark this situation is not contemplated. Every person in my class has a personal laptop. The software is not OS specific.

Comment: As a side note, it might be genuinely impossible for the school to give you a key. If they have some sort of campus-wide academic license for the software, installation may require the licence administrator to log in to their account from your computer. Matlab is an example of this. (Speaking from my own experience, needing a specific person to come to my office to set it up. )

Comment: @InquisitiveLurker It may be, but I had a Matlab licence with my past institution and they surely did not require unrestricted access to my machine.

Comment: Make a complete backup, then remove all the users and create a new user. Let then install with that new user . Once complete then add back your other users from the backup...

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: I agree with your suggestion, but I am not sure remarks like "trick them" or "not easily recognisable" are appropriate here. We do not actually know they use the software installation as a pretext to carry out any malicious plan with the OP's computer. Instead, I'd consider it a legitimate idea to openly offer giving the university access to a restricted user account with a VM within which the IT people have sufficient rights to install stuff.

Comment: “_I have contacted the responsible for my course_”: do you mean the professor teaching the course? If not, I suggest asking the professor and explaining your privacy concerns, they may be more sympathetic and may be able to instruct the IT staff and the “responsible for the course” (assuming that’s someone less powerful such as a teaching assistant or staff member) to acccommodate your request, or at least propose a mechanism that will allow the IT staff to install the software without raising concerns about violating your privacy.

Comment: If no root password is required, installing in a separate user account may be sufficient (assuming that the system is reasonably safe and the technicians are not adversarial).

Comment: Another solution: get a second hard disc, install a basic OS (for example from a linux live cd) and let them install their software there. When you have your computer back, add your original disc(s) and set up a multiboot option.

Comment: @InquisitiveLurker: Matlab's not a good example. My campus has a universal Matlab license that did not require administrator assistance.

Comment: Encryption is your friend.

Comment: @InquisitiveLurker Matlab doesn't need that. We have a campus licence for Matlab for 30k+ students, and each one can install their copy through the Mathworks site.

Comment: I'm curious to know how it ended up.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano The uni said it's not possible for me to be present during the installation. The uni does not offer this software on its machines and requires some assignments to be done specifically with this software. Long story short, I decided to not have the software installed and everybody is treating me as the weirdo because I won't give my computer in.

Answer (score 22):

> My university requires unrestricted access to my personal computer for an afternoon to install a certain software.

Your university has messed up. Are you really sure that it's the university requiring this? Maybe it's the isolated action of your professor, in agreement with their department IT (not the university one).

> He has explicitly stated that there are no alternatives to the standard process of giving in my computer to the tech department for one afternoon.

I've never, ever seen an academic software licence requiring such a procedure.

> On one side am reluctant to give unrestricted access to my computer for security reasons

You're rightly reluctant.

> How can I avoid giving unrestricted access to my personal machine while still obtaining this software?

First, contact your course mates to start a collective action. I suggest you to write an email, signed by all students, to the dean supervising the courses of your field, the head of the department to which your professor belongs to, and, if there is one, the head of the IT university service. Copy the email to the rector too. Express clearly your concerns and state that is totally unacceptable to require students to give access to their personal computers. If your university insists on this position, ask them a copy of the licence agreement.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to look elsewhere for legal advice, but from an academic point of view this is extremely unusual.

Most academic software licenses make a distinction between software that is allowed to be installed on student's personal machines and software that is only allowed to be installed on university-owned machines. For student software the software distributor always has some mechanism in place to allow students to achieve that installation on their own.

As to why your university has instituted this policy we cannot guess.

1) *Politely* inform your technology department that you are not comfortable handing over your personal property and ask that you be allowed to perform the installation yourself. This is a reasonable request that should be accommodated. If they refuse, ask them to be specific as to why.

2) If nothing else, *politely* insist that you schedule a time so they can conduct the installation with you present. Most software installations take just a few minutes but at worst take an hour or two. Again, this is a reasonable request. If they refuse, ask them to be specific as to why.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed very odd. If you are sufficiently tech-savvy to do this, one option may be to set up a virtual machine that they can install the software onto. They can have root access to that, without needing permissions to browse your computer.

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is personal files that are currently on your machine, then moving them onto an external hard drive and back should address that. If the concern is whether the software will have access to personal files in the future, an option would be buying a computer just for this software. And as Flyto says, a vitual machine is another option, but if you're really paranoid, that's not as secure, as they will still have physical access to the entire machine.

Comment: If you are worried about the university accessing other parts of the machine (outside the virtual machine), then what else should you be worried about? They might (perhaps not intentionally) install malware on the machine. In that case, moving the files off the computer and then back again is not secure either (unless you can be sure of removing any such malware first).